# How to use apex_string.split?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to split a string : `OK#15#78` by #

I would like to get the first part of the string : Ok

I tried the following queries but it's not working :

```
select apex_string.split('OK#15#78','#')[0] from dual;
```

What can I try next?

Comment: It also works with clob...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `TABLE` and rownum:

```
SELECT val
FROM (Select rownum AS rn, column_value AS val
     FROM TABLE(apex_string.split('OK#15#78','#')))
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: actually, this will likely bring issues, because APEX_STRING.SPLIT results in a nested table, and there is guarantee that the order will be the same when you run it multiple times. You should rather use the regxp_substr method

Answer (score 1):

**ORIGNAL POST:**

Even simpler:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE val, ROWNUM
FROM apex_string.split('OK#15#78','#')
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Or maybe even faster:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE val
FROM apex_string.split('OK#15#78','#')
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

**REVISED ANSWER**

There is a caveat here: APEX_STRING.SPLIT results in a nested table, and there are no guarantees about the order of the returned items, so this actually doesn't work.

You should use the regxp_substr method

```
SELECT val c
FROM 
(
   (SELECT regexp_substr('OK#15#78','[^#]+', 1, level) 
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(, '[^#]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)
)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```